# Unable to connect to Ejabberd server

Tags: swift, xmpp, ejabberd, adium

I have installed ejabberd version 17.06 on my mac. I could connect to it using Adium and Swift. But after a while after logging out of Adium and Swift I am unable to connect. The server seems to work fine as I am able to navigate the admin panel and create users. I tried uninstalling and installing back, but no use. Tried other latest version too. Nothing in the logs too.

This same behavior happened 2 days back. The clients are unable to connect after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had to set the host as localhost, which I did not have to do before.

Hope it helps someone.